# R code required :How to bring column data in Rows uniquely

Tags: r

I have the following data:

[image: SAMPLE DATA]

```
id       client number year-month revenue
2        748 2014-12  92.25
3        748 2015-01  84.00
4        748 2015-06 751.89
5        749 2015-07 913.35
6        749 2015-08 334.96
```

I want the output as

[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

```
client number  2014-12 2014-01 2015-06 2015-07 2015-08
748              92.25    84.00  751.89  0      0
749                0       0      0      913.35  334.96
```

I want to do this in R

Comment: Can you please reformat your expected input and output, it's tough to interpret it at the moment.

Comment: Click on the sample data and expected output